# Illustrator: Different stroke weight on a line path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

How to have a different stroke weight on a single line path? I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHr4EumeApo&t=376s) — what is the process to create that clock needle? Thanks.

Exact time for my question is 6:16 to 6:24.

Comment: Look up "Width tool illustrator tutorial". There's one here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g93VnyveQxI&ab_channel=Dansky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways in Illustrator, that you can use:

1. Using Variable Width Profiles

[image]

2. List item

[image]

Clock example:

[image]

You can round the corners of the strokes using Stroke properties. And 2nd method works on closed stroke paths like circle too.

Comment: thanks! able to create the effect using method 2.